# decompressing compressed binary file

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, gzip, zlib

i have compressed file (binary file/compressed string - **i'm not sure what it is**),
i'am trying to decompress this file by c#/vb.net ,
i tried to decompress it with Gzip:

```
 Private Shared Function gzuncompress(ByVal data() As Byte) As Byte()
        Dim input As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(data)
        Dim gzip As GZipStream = New GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress)
        Dim output As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
        gzip.CopyTo(output)
        Return output.ToArray
    End Function
```

```
gzuncompress(New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData("http://haxball.com/list3"))
```

but there is an exception (where : gzip.CopyTo(output)):

```
The magic number in GZip header is not correct
```

but when i tried to uncompress it by php it's worked :) .

```
php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$list = file_get_contents('http://haxball.com/list3');

$list = gzuncompress($list);

$len = implode('', unpack('n*', $list));

$bytes = unpack('c*', $list);

$string = implode('', array_map('chr', $bytes));

echo $string;
```

you can check the code here:

http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php

someone have the php's gzuncompress c#/vb.net alternative?

Even if there is a extarnal exe file that can do the same as the php's gzuncompress function it will be very good answer,

kind of:

```
Process.start("c:\umcompress.exe -f c:\list3 -o c:\res.txt")
```

Note:A good example is better than explanation

Update:
The First 30 Bytes Of The File:

```
78 DA 8C BD 79 F4 5D D7 55 26 78 65 0D F1 24 0F 89 E3 98 4C 5C 47 21 71 E2 C8 B9 E7 9E E1
```

Comment: conclusion: it the compression must not be GZip compatible

Comment: Just as I thought, so if php's gzuncompress can decompress it maybe it's compressed string? (if it is, what should i do to decompress compressed string by c#/vb.net?), note: this is the file :http://haxball.com/list3 (what do you think it is?) (yes, i got alot of questions because this is the first time that i ever tried anything like it)

Comment: I recommend that you look into DotNetZip, I've used it several times and its always been better than the built-in classes in the framework -- http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Comment: ok,thanks (i think that i alredy checked it but i will check it again).

Comment: No gzip header. Might be deflate.

Comment: Add the first 30 bytes of the compressed data in hexadecimal to your question.

Answer (score 1):

That is a [zlib](http://zlib.net/) stream.  The zlib format is described in [RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950), and consists of a two-byte header and a four-byte trailer around a deflate stream.  You will need to write your own code to process the header and trailer, and you can use the [DeflateStream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to decompress the deflate stream.

Or you can use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) which will process the zlib stream directly.